# Self hosted NServiceBus not reading the queue

Tags: nservicebus

I'm running NSB 3.2.8 self-hosted in an MVC4 app, this is my config:

```
Configure.With()
.DefiningMessagesAs(t => t.Namespace != null && namespaces.Contains(t.Namespace))
.CastleWindsorBuilder(container)
.XmlSerializer()
.Log4Net()
.MsmqTransport()
    .IsTransactional(true)
    .IsolationLevel(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted)
    .PurgeOnStartup(false)                  
.UnicastBus()
.ImpersonateSender(false)
.CreateBus()
.Start();
```

I can add a dependency to `IBus` in my controllers and send messages into the queue with `Bus.SendLocal()` but the queue is not being read from and there is no log4net log file being created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't mention what queue you expect it to read from. Since an MVC-hosted app does not have an `IConfigureThisEndpoint` class to infer the endpoint name, you should use `.DefineEndpointName("MyEndpoint")` right after `Configure.With()` to do so - this will set the name for the input queue, if applicable.

The other issue that I see is that after `.UnicastBus()` you would need to call `.LoadMessageHandlers()` to declare your intent to process messages in the MVC app. Many times a web application will be a send-only endpoint, and so there is no need to create an input queue or process any messages from it. Calling this method will scan your types for message handlers, and begin reading from the queue.

Comment: It has created the queue, it picks up the endpoint name from the namespace of where you called `Configure`

Comment: I tried adding both of these, it's still not processing the queue

Comment: Ok, so I deleted all the queues, restarted the site & it's started working.  Makes no sense, but `LoadMessageHandlers` was probably what helped :)

Comment: It's possible that the queue originally got created with the wrong permissions. Sometimes I run into that issue when I forget to set up the identity for an IIS application pool and then change it, and then I delete the queue, it gets recreated, and everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `Configure.WithWeb()`

Also, how do you define the name of your endpoint?

Comment: Configure.WithWeb() has been deprecated. Configure.With() is now able to sense what environment it is being run in and scan the assemblies in either the web application's bin directory or the normal endpoint's base directory, as appropriate.